# virtual machine or dual boot when measuring code performance

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

i am trying to measure code performance (basically speed-up when using threads). So far i was using cygwin via windows or linux on separate machine. Now i have the ability to set up a new system and i am not sure whether i should have dual boot (windows and ubuntu) or a virtual machine.

My concern is whether i can measure reliable speed up and possibly other stuff (performance monitors) via a linux virtual machine or if i have to go with with normal booting in linux.

anybody have an opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "threading" relies heavily on scheduling, I won't recommend you to use VM.  VM is just a normal process from the host OS's point of view, so the guest kernel and its scheduler will be affected by scheduling by the host kernel.

If your "threading" is more like parallel computation, I think it's OK to use VM.

Comment: actually i want to run pthread based programs and check how speed up scales with number of threads. This is parallel computation i guess so i can get reliable results from a VM if i don't touch scheduling? But if i develop some customization affecting scheduling i shouldn't be able to get something reliable? do i understand you correctly ?

Comment: You are correct.  If you are going to evaluate the details of scheduling, VM's are not for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer! by the way although not exactly in the topic do you have any idea about performance measurements via Cygwin? are they reliable?

Comment: Cygwin is built on top of very complex UNIX-Windows compatibility layers.  When it comes to performance measurement, it is the last platform I would use.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is much safer to boot directly on the system and avoid using a VM in your case. Even when you don't use a VM, it is already hard to have twice the same results in multi-threading because the system being used for OS tasks, so having 2 OS running in the same time as for VM even increases the uncertainty on the results. For instance, running your tests 1000 times on a VM would lead to, let's say, 100 over-estimated time, while it would maybe be only 60 on a lonely OS. It is your call to know if this uncertainty is acceptable or not.